# Matching two subsequent words with a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

> The Wild won 2 - 1 over the Flames.

I need to extract the team names and the scores from that string. In Python I did the following:

```
 foo = re.findall(r'The (\w+) won (\d+) - (\d+) over the (\w+)\.', mystring)
```

Now the problem is, there are team names with whitespace in it like this:

> The Red Wings won 4 - 3 over the Blue Jackets.

How would I go about writing a regexp that matches both of those string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just edit your original regex to include spaces in the team name groups:

```
foo = re.findall(r'The ([\w ]+) won (\d+) - (\d+) over the ([\w ]+)\.', mystring)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `([\w ]+)` instead of `(\w+)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is really that consistent, you can just relax your expression a little and it'll work fine:

```
foo = re.findall(r'The (.+) won (.+) - (.+) over the (.+).', mystring)
```